# Indexes and performance

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, postgis, geotools

I'm new to Geotools and facing this issue : I'm injecting in PostGis about 2MB of shapefile info (about 5800 entries) and surprisingly it takes more or less 6 minutes to complete! Quite annoying because my "real" data set might be up to 25MB by shapefile group (shp, dbf...), 100 groups needed.

I was told that it might be an index issue, because Postgre updates tables' indexes on each INSERT. Is there a way to "disable" these indexes during my mass INSERTs and tell the database to create all indexes on the end? Or is there a better way to do that?

Here is my code snippet :

```
Map<String, Object> shpparams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
shpparams.put("url", "file://" + path);
FileDataStore shpStore = (FileDataStore) shpFactory.createDataStore(shpparams);
SimpleFeatureCollection features = shpStore.getFeatureSource().getFeatures();
if (schema == null) {
    // Copy schema and change name in order to refer to the same
    // global schema for all files
    SimpleFeatureType originalSchema = shpStore.getSchema();
    Name originalName = originalSchema.getName();
    NameImpl theName = new NameImpl(originalName.getNamespaceURI(), originalName.getSeparator(), POSTGIS_TABLENAME);
    schema = factory.createSimpleFeatureType(theName, originalSchema.getAttributeDescriptors(), originalSchema.getGeometryDescriptor(),
            originalSchema.isAbstract(), originalSchema.getRestrictions(), originalSchema.getSuper(), originalSchema.getDescription());
    pgStore.createSchema(schema);
}
// String typeName = shpStore.getTypeNames()[0];
SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) pgStore.getFeatureSource(POSTGIS_TABLENAME);

// Ajout des objets du shapefile dans la table PostGIS
DefaultTransaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");
featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
try {
    featureStore.addFeatures(features);
    transaction.commit();
} catch (Exception problem) {
    LOGGER.error(problem.getMessage(), problem);
    transaction.rollback();
} finally {
    transaction.close();
}
shpStore.dispose();
```

Thank you for your help!

---

So I tested your solutions but nothing helped me more... The completion time is still the same. Here is my table definition :

- fid   serial  10
- the_geom  geometry    2147483647
- xxx   varchar 10
- xxx   int4    10
- xxx   varchar 3
- xxx   varchar 2
- xxx   float8  17
- xxx   float8  17
- xxx   float8  17

So I do not think that the problem is directly linked to my code or the database, maybe it is due to system limitations (RAM, buffers...). I will have a look at this in the next few days.

Do you have more ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is in the database? How many records are you inserting? If the issue is in the indices update, you can turn off autocommit and do one commit at the end of your inserts.

Comment: you should post your table definition, including all indexes. best way: in psql program, type `\d your_table_name`.

Comment: @Minras: it will not help... and I think pef is already using one transaction, look at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm back with the solution for this problem. After many investigations, I found that the physical network was the issue : with a local DB (local to geotools app) there were no problem. The network added 200 or 300 millisec to each INSERT statement request. With the large amount of data injected in DB came the very long response time!

So no problem with the orignal Postgis config or my code snippet...

Thank you all for your participation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if indexes or PK/FK constraints in the database are really the bottleneck with the following steps:

1) Make sure the data is inserted in a single transaction (disable autocommit)

2) Drop all indexes and re-create them after the data import (you cannot *disable* an index)

```
DROP INDEX my_index;
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table (my_column);
```

3) Drop or disable PK/FK constraints and re-create or re-enable them after the data import. You can skip the check of PK/FK constraints during data import without dropping them with

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DISABLE trigger ALL;
-- data import
ALTER TABLE my_table ENABLE trigger ALL;
```

The downside of this approach is that the PK/FK **constraints are not checked** for the data that was inserted/updated while the check was disabled. Of course the PK/FK constraints are enforced also for existing data when you re-create them after the data import.

You can also defer the check of PK/FK constraints to the end of a transaction. This is possible if and only if the PK/FK constraint is defined as *deferrable* (not the default):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

START TRANSACTION;
-- data import
COMMIT; -- constraints are checked here
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

START TRANSACTION;
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
-- data import
COMMIT; -- constraints are checked here
```

**EDIT:**

To narrow down the cause of the problem you can import the data with your application, make a database dump (with insert statements) and import that database dump again. This should give you an idea of how long the plain import takes and what's the overhead of the application.

Create a data-only dump of the database with `INSERT` statements (`COPY` statements would be faster, but your application also uses inserts so this is better for comparison):

`pg_dump <database> --data-only --column-inserts -f data.sql`

Create the empty database schema again and import the data (with basic timing):

`date; psql <database> --single-transaction -f data.sql > /dev/null; date`

Maybe you can get a little more insight into the problem with this.

Comment: So I tested your solutions but nothing helped me more... The completion time is still the same. Here is my table definition :
`
    * fid serial 10
    * the_geom geometry 2147483647
    * xxx varchar 10
    * xxx int4 10
    * xxx varchar 3
    * xxx varchar 2
    * xxx float8 17
    * xxx float8 17
    * xxx float8 17
`
So I do not think that the problem is directly linked to my code or the database, maybe it is due to system limitations (RAM, buffers...). I will have a look at this in the next few days.

Do you have more ideas?

Comment: @pef: I've added some steps to narrow down the problem to my original answer.

Comment: I tested your solution : dumping tables and re-populate them with INSERT script let me reduce the time to 4min (2min less). I do not really know if this is a great improvement but seems too slow again. I still think it is a Postgre configuration issue. Maybe some tuning will help?

Comment: @pef: Well, 4 minutes for 2MB, that's really way too slow. I don't think it's a PostgreSQL configuration issue, since we are talking about inserts here (tuning is mostly relevant for query performance). What hardware, OS and PostgreSQL version are you running on? Is the data confidential? If you could upload the dump somewhere I would like to try an import it on my system.

Comment: Ok, thank you to confirm me this. And yes my datas are confidential so with your clues I will focus on improving hardware configuration... But now this will be checked next year! :) To be continued.

Comment: Hi and Happy new year!
I'm coming back with these performance issues. I looked closer at the database configuration and saw it is configured with basic recommended parameters, like described in postgre documentation (for shared_buffer, wal_buffer...). So is this the problem? Maybe more tuning is needed for this kind of massive binary data?
I also logged the queries launched by geotools, they look like massive inserts : `INSERT INTO myTable ( "the_geom",... ) VALUES ( GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((843130.7990000003 6539900.688999995, 843377.9080000003...', -1),'001',23,'001','',5.87,0.0,0.0)`

Comment: What does `GeomFromText()` do, is this an expensive function? What does an example insert statement from the SQL dump look like and how many insert statements are there in the dump?

Comment: This method is used AFAIK to convert polygon description (geometry) to a long binary data (storable in DB). The dump of my test case contains about 8500 lines and SQL inserts look like the one presented above except for the first column that is a very long byte sequence. I'm currently studying the overhead caused by the `GeomFromText()` method but I don't think this is the issue : reproducing inserts from the dump (with already converted bytes sequences) gave the same execution time. Maybe is it due to the really big size of this binary field ("the_geom")? Still investigating...